# Change css background image on a div for multiple pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this CSS:

```
div[data-role="page"]{ 
min-height: 100%;
width: 100%;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
border: 0px;
background-image:url('../img/blue_background.jpg');}
```

and this is my function:

Note:
on the variables initialized in the function, the val() is from a selectbox that when changed, is saved in localStorage.

```
function saveParam(){
var result=$("#param_results option:selected").val();
var scan=$("#param_scan option:selected").val();
var scan_speed=$("#param_scan_speed option:selected").val();
var scan_bg=$("#param_scan_bg option:selected").val();
var font=$("#param_font option:selected").val();
var screen_bg=$("#param_screen_bg option:selected").val();
var waiting_time=$("#param_waiting_time option:selected").val();

window.localStorage.setItem("param_results", result);
window.localStorage.setItem("param_scan", scan);
window.localStorage.setItem("param_scan_speed", scan_speed);
window.localStorage.setItem("param_scan_bg", scan_bg);
window.localStorage.setItem("param_font", font);
window.localStorage.setItem("param_screen_bg", screen_bg);
window.localStorage.setItem("param_waiting_time", waiting_time);


//$('div[data-role="page"]').css("background-image", "url('../img/green.jpg')");

back();}
```

I have several html pages, all of them have the div[data-role="page"] so all of them have the same background, etc... but when param_screen_bg is changed, I want to permanently change the background image to another but it's not working. The comment line at the end it's just my attempt to try to change the background but it's still not working.

EDIT:
https://jsfiddle.net/42zbcbge/1/

on this jsfiddle is a small example of what i want. when you press the save button, i want to change the background on the css and therefor on the page too but it's not changing

Comment: by `permanently change` you mean that this picture will be used in future ?

Comment: every time that "param_screen_bg" is changed, the background is changed too. so by permanently i mean that until someone on the app change it, the background will be the new image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey i didn't completely understood the code which you have added. But, i guess you are using selectbox and passing image url in option's value.
So while fetching, you should only use the id of selectbox, like :

```
var screen_bg=$("#param_screen_bg").val();
```

instead of

```
var screen_bg=$("#param_screen_bg option:selected").val();

var bg_image_value = localStorage.getItem("param_screen_bg");

if(bg_image_value != null && bg_image_value != '') {
   $('div[data-role="page"]').css("background-image", 'url('+bg_image_value+')' ); 
}
```

May be try adding code in codepen or jsfiddle.

Comment: Yes that's sort of it. but to get the selected option don't i need the option:selected? but still, after that, how do i change the background image on the css permanently?

Comment: no there is no need to use option:selected to get value from selectbox    var bg_image_value = localStorage.getItem("param_screen_bg"); if(bg_image_value != null && bg_image_value != '') { $('div[data-role="page"]').css("background-image", url(bg_image_value) ); } }

Comment: thx for the help but i can get the value of the var but the thing is when i apply the css change on the div it doesn't change the background, just get a white background

Comment: can you upload code on jsfiddle or codepen or else see if background-image is properly assigned to page div using inspect element.
would be better if you upload code on jsfiddle or upload screenshot of inspected element

Comment: Try using on click event instead of passing function name in button

$('button').on('click', function() {

$('div#param').css("background-image", "url('http://www.spyderonlines.com/images/wallpapers/green-background-images/green-background-images-16.jpg')");

});

and ofcourse remove saveParam() from button

Comment: already changed the jsfiddle with your suggestion and not working. when press the button nothing happens

Comment: You had not included js library file.
i have updated fiddle, please check again

Comment: thx mate, it solved on the example. but somehow on my project i'm not managing to get it work. i have a .js file with all the functions and some .html files with different pages. to define that function i only need the id of the button right? or on the js file need to define something on that function to relate it to the specific html page where the button is?

Comment: I think there is some problem with .setItem

i still don't think, option:selected.val(), is a right way to fetch selectbox value.

Comment: the thing is that i comment that lines on the function just to see if would change the bg with a direct image but still th button don't even works. the code of the button now is:
    '$("#saveParam").on('click', function() {
    $('div[data-role="page"]').css("background-image", "url('../img/green.jpg')");
    
    back(); });'

Comment: please check jsfiddle again : 
https://jsfiddle.net/42zbcbge/3/

the button works there

Comment: maybe it's some problem on my js file, i must check again. but yes, the button on the jsfiddle is working, thx a lot mate for the help ;)

Comment: see in console if you get any error message.

on fiddle the js library was not included

Answer (score 0):

You're `setting` the values in the localStorage, but you never seem to `get` 'm.
So, you could, for example, do something like this:

```js
jQuery().ready(function() //do when page is loaded
{
  if(window.localStorage.getItem("param_screen_bg") !== null) //check if value is set in localStorage
  {
    //get value from localStorage and apply it to the div:
    $('div[data-role="page"]').css("background-image", window.localStorage.getItem("param_screen_bg"));
  }
});
```

I'm making some assumptions in this sample though, but I think you can handle it ;)

Comment: thx for the reply, i have the get item on a method above this code i posted but the thing is when i apply css changes to div, the background don't change to the new image, instead of it, change to a white background :s

Comment: Check the value you are setting and getting at the localStorage and the value you set to the CSS. Is it correct CSS? You could use your browsers inspector to see what has been set.